# Hello, what it means "the abrupt surge of the hill"?

Tags: meaning

what it means "the abrupt surge of the hill"?
I think it's about the steepness of the hill. But when "abrupt" and "surge" joined together it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Context is needed!!!

Comment: Some context would be useful. As it is, I would guess it means that the angle of the slope changes sharply rather than gradually.

Comment: It's from "The Hill of Dreams" by Arthur Machen (1863-1947) a Welsh fantasy writer. "Then he had climbed the abrupt surge of the hill, and passing the green and swelling battlements, the ring of oaks, and the matted thicket,"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *surge* is a [fairly sudden] increase in height or volume, and *abrupt* could easily describe that.

In this case, it's likely to be an [escarpment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/escarpment): a steep slope rising sharply. A picture is worth a thousand words...

[image: Line drawing of escarpment]

Answer (score 0):

**surge** has this sense:  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/194918?rskey=NS5P0J&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> transf. in reference to various physical things, as fire, wind,
>   sound; also to **‘rolling’ or undulating hills** or the like.

And from [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/surge)

> rise rapidly

As in:

> ... he had climbed the **rapidly rising hill**, and...